# Scheduled reminders - nothing happens

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Civicrm 5.38.0, Joomla version

I've set up a scheduled reminder which is supposed to trigger three hours before an activity, and send me an email. The (hourly) job executes fine - job log shows success. But nothing actually happens. No email, no record of an activity, no entry in civicrm_action_log. In fact civicrm_action_log seems to be permanently empty - is this normal?.

Same result whether the job is executed by cron or manually ("execute now"). In both cases the job is run with Superuser permissions.

I assume that the scheduled reminder is just not triggering. The question is - why?

Before I start delving into the code, which looks quite daunting, I'm hoping someone can suggest a simpler way of tracking down where the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: Before looking at the code, I'd suggest some more experiments to be sure that you have scheduled the reminder for the right time right sort of participants etc. Are other jobs triggering OK (e.g. do a test bulk mailing)? I'm not sure what you mean by civicrm_action_log.

Comment: Thanks. All jobs are triggering ok. I've done a bit more digging, and I think the problem was probably caused by having the backtrace option ticked in the debug settings. Will test and confirm.

Comment: So frustrating. I was able to get a scheduled reminder to send based on an activity. But there seem to be multiple unintuitive conditions which cause the reminder to fail silently. For example, if I set the SR to send to my contact record using "choose recipient", it fails. But if I set the same SR to send to my contact record as Assignee, it works. I've had a quick look at the relevant parts of the code, andI fear there may be other such conditions hiding in there. Has anyone attempted to document this? If not, I'm willing to have a go, but I would need some pointers as to where to look.

Comment: Can anyone help? I'm looking for information on anything which can cause a scheduled reminder to be ignored. Thank you.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible for you to show a screenshot of your SR settings?  Also can you show the source code for the SR html format.  Recently I had similar failures of SR's and found the source code to be the probable culprit.

Comment: Thanks @peterb. I'm pretty sure that the SR itself isn't the issue (in any case, the HTML is just a few words, such as "This is a test". Apparently, the SR will reliably send to the activity Assignees, but not to specified email addresses (or not to my address anyway). Also, the schedule repetition seems to depend on the original schedule triggering. So, if you add an activity which has a date after the scheduled reminder date, the repetitions don't trigger. I suspect there may be other constraints, too. All in all, we decided to try using CiviRules instead.